# require.context() alternative when using ES modules

Tags: webpack, require, es6-modules

I have a project where I want to use ES modules and use `import` instead of `require`.

So I have added in `package.json` `"type": "module"`.

There is a case now where I have to import some files and the only way I know to do that is by using `require.context`.

---

My file (which auto-imports routes):

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

/*
 * Auto imports routes from @/pages. It only requires a route.js file inside each page
 * */
function autoImportRoutes() {
  const filePaths = require.context('@/pages/', true, /route.js/)
  console.log(filePaths.keys())
  return filePaths.keys().map(filePath => {
    const pathWithoutLeadingDot = filePath.replace('.', '') // remove first dot of ./path-name
    return require(`@/pages${pathWithoutLeadingDot}`).default
  })
}

const routes = autoImportRoutes()

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

---

The error I get:

```
(node:36528) Warning: require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of babel.config.js from project-path\no
de_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\module-types.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename babel.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from project-path\package.js
on.
```

If I remove, the `"type": "module"` from `package.json` everything works, but I wanted to know if there is a way to make this work.

I understand that `require.context()` (probably) is not allowed when using ES modules, but then how to do the same functionality without using `require.context()` ?

---

**Update:** I searched this a bit and it seems that it's not possible to do what I want (at least without hacking around with node file system) by using ES modules for 2 reasons.

1. Haven't found an import alternative to `require.context()`
2. `import()` it asynchronous which will make my code fail because `vue-router` doesn't waits. Could be workarounds to make it wait though, but too hacky.

So right now, I will stick with removing `"type": "module"` from `package.json`

Any answer is welcome and thanks for your time :)

Comment: Are you using some bundler or other build tool (webpack, metro, etc?)

Comment: Yes I am using webpack and require.context is a webpack specific thing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (in fact, aren't supposed to) use `require` with `require.context`. The context object itself is callable, and will require the relevant module when called with the relevant key. Your import function should be:

```js
function autoImportRoutes() {
  const filePaths = require.context('@/pages/', true, /route.js/)
  return filePaths.keys().map(filePath => {
    return filePaths(filePath).default
  })
}
```